# Docker-compose cache of build images in Travis CI for Cypress

Tags: docker, caching, docker-compose, travis-ci

I have docker-compose file, that sets up 3 containers: frontend, backend and Cypress.

I want to cache Cypress container in order to reduce time for Cypress install.

What should I do with Travis CI configuration in order to cache only that image?

I cannot cache frontend image, because on build stage I have production build of frontend static files that must be rebuilt each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the easiest way to cache images in TravisCI of specific image is to use `docker load` and `docker save` in before_cache/script and after_script sections respectively.
Example: https://travis-ci.org/DucaturFw/ducor-frontend/jobs/413076534/config

But better way is to use Cypress on host by `cypress run` with testing URL set to localhost, which is where docker-compose instances of the service would come.
Caching cypress by adding `~/.npm` into `cache` section of travis CI settings.
Example: https://travis-ci.org/DucaturFw/ducor-frontend/jobs/413177816/config